# Use Netmiko to loop through file and get switch ARP entries

Tags: python, networking, netmiko

I am trying to output the ARP table of a switch by using Netmiko. I would like to use a file containing IP addresses and then have Python/Netmiko run a "show arp" and then add the IP address from the file I give. I would like it to loop through the IP address file to show all ARP entries for the IP addresses in the file and then output to a file containing both IP and MAC addresses. Below is what I have for a single address any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#CF extract ARP table and send output as text file

from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys

##initializing device
device = {
    'device_type': 'hp_comware',
    'ip': '10.1.10.10',
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxx',
}
start_time = datetime.now()
print (start_time)

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
output = net_connect.send_command("dis arp 172.16.100.100")
time.sleep(2)
filename="test-arp.txt"
saveconfig=open(filename, 'w+')
saveconfig.write(output)
saveconfig.close()
time.sleep(2)
net_connect.disconnect()
end_time = datetime.now()
print (end_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code below, you can perform the operation very quickly on 100 devices at the same time (you can increase it if you want) in accordance with the promt of the device.

```
from netmiko import Netmiko
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time

f_2 = open("multiple_device_list_cisco.txt","r") # You should open a notepad with this name and add all the IPs one under the other.
multiple_device_list = f_2.readlines()

file1 = open("Result.txt", "a") # this will be your automatic output when the code is finished

def _ssh_(nodeip):

    try:
        hp = {
            'device_type': 'hp_comware', 'ip': nodeip, 'username':
            xxxx, 'password': xxxx, 'secret':xxxx, "conn_timeout": 20}
        hp_connect = Netmiko(**hp)
        print(nodeip.strip() + "  " + "is reachable")
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        f_3.write(nodeip.strip() + "\n")
        return

    prompt_hp_fnk = hp_connect.find_prompt()
    hostname_fnk = prompt_hp_fnk.strip("#") # Here you should put whatever the prompt of your HP device is
    print(hostname_fnk)
    output = hp_connect.send_command_timing("dis arp "+ nodeip)
    file1.write(nodeip +" "+ output+ "\n")
    hp_connect.disconnect()

myPool = ThreadPool(100) # you can increase or decrease this value
result = myPool.map(_ssh_,multiple_device_list)
```

I wrote the necessary changes to the above code. I hope that will be useful

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am not trying to run this command on multiple devices. I have a file with IP addresses that I want to use instead of supplying one IP at time. So I want the "dis arp ..." to pull the IP addresses from a file and loop through it and then the output file will contain the MAC and IP.

Comment: Hi @EchelonSS; I edited the code. > dis arp nodeip(X.X.X.X) . For example, for 100 IPs, it will be able to run dis arp X.X.X.X to all IPs in notepad. Please try it.

Comment: It seems to work without the \n I tried your code but getting an error: File "./20220428-comware-arp-loop.py", line 28
    output = hp_connect.send_command_timing("dis arp "+ nodeip\n)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: I updated this part of the code, can you try again? ==> output = hp_connect.send_command_timing("dis arp "+ nodeip)

Comment: yes it works, I can't thank you enough for your help, now at least I can use sed or awk to remove the unneeded output. Thank you so much.